# Evaluation of a general trigonometric integral

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

How can I evaluate the integral

$$\int\sin^k(x)\ dx$$

in which I don't know if $k$ is an even or an odd number?

Comment: Are you supposed to know about complex numbers?

Comment: Yes! By the way, my real integral is from 0 to $\pi$, but I would also like to know the general method..

Comment: My answer below concerns the indefinite integral. It's not the best method when your integral goes from $0$ to $\pi/2$, which is a Wallis integral. From $0$ to $\pi$, you get two times a Wallis integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \sin^k x$.

We have $\sin x = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$. So 
$$
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \frac{1}{(2i)^k}(e^{ix} - e^{-ix})^k \\
&=\frac{1}{(2i)^k} \sum_{j = 0}^k \binom{k}{j} (e^{ix})^{k-j} (-e^{-ix})^j \\
&=\frac{1}{(2i)^k} \sum_{j = 0}^k (-1)^j \binom{k}{j} e^{(k-2j)ix} \\
&=\frac{1}{(2i)^k} \left(\sum_{0 \leq j < k/2} \left[(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}e^{(k-2j)ix} + (-1)^{k-j} \binom{k}{k-j}e^{(2j-k)ix} \right] + \varepsilon (-1)^{k/2}\binom{k}{k/2}\right), 
\end{align*}
$$
where the term with $\varepsilon$ appears only if $k$ is even, and then $\varepsilon = 1$. On the last line, we've grouped together symmetric terms of the sum. From here on, we distinguish between even $k$ and odd $k$.

If $k$ is even, say $k = 2m$, then
$$
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \frac{(-1)^m}{2^{2m}} \left[ \sum_{j = 0}^{m-1} (-1)^{j}  \binom{2m}{j} \left(e^{2(m-j)ix} + e^{2(j-m)ix}\right) + (-1)^m\binom{2m}{m} \right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2^{2m}} \left[ \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} (-1)^{m-j} \binom{2m}{j} \cdot 2 \cos 2(m-j)x + \binom{2m}{m} \right] \\
&=\frac{1}{2^{2m-1}} \sum_{h = 1}^m (-1)^h \binom{2m}{m-h} \cos 2hx + \frac{1}{2^{2m}}\binom{2m}{m},
\end{align*}
$$
which is easy to integrate. (From $0$ to $\pi$, only the last term has a nonzero integral.) The last term is like half what the term for $h = 0$ would be. For example, for $k = 6$, we get
$$\sin^6 x =  \frac{20}{64} - \frac{15}{32} \cos 2x + \frac{6}{32} \cos 4x - \frac{1}{32} \cos 6x  $$

If $k$ is odd, say $k = 2m + 1$, then we have 
$$
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \frac{(-1)^{m}}{2^{2m}} \sum_{j = 0}^m (-1)^j \binom{2m+1}{j} \frac{e^{[2(m-j) + 1]x} - e^{-[2(m-j) + 1]x}}{2i} \\
&=\frac{1}{2^{2m}} \sum_{j = 0}^m (-1)^{m-j} \binom{2m+1}{j} \sin [2(m-j) + 1]x \\
&=\frac{1}{2^{2m}} \sum_{h = 0}^m (-1)^{h} \binom{2m+1}{m-h} \sin (2h + 1)x,
\end{align*}
$$
which is again easy to integrate. From $0$ to $\pi$, this last formula won't immediately give you the simplest form of the integral, which is twice the [Wallis integral.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals) Also, there are some circumstances where it might be preferable to integrate directly from one of the complex forms of $f(x)$, using the fact that the integral of $e^{inx}$ is $\displaystyle \frac{e^{inx}}{in}$.

For $k = 7$, we get 
$$\sin^7 x = \frac{35}{64} \sin x - \frac{21}{64} \sin 3x + \frac{7}{64} \sin 5x - \frac{1}{64} \sin 7x.$$

Comment: Perfect, simply.

Answer (score 4):

We can also use integration by parts to reduce the integral to either $\int\sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ or $\int1\,\mathrm{d}x$.
$$
\begin{align}
\int\sin^n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=-\int\sin^{n-1}(x)\,\mathrm{d}\cos(x)\tag{1}\\
&=-\cos(x)\sin^{n-1}(x)+(n-1)\int\sin^{n-2}(x)\cos^2(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}\\
&=-\frac1n\cos(x)\sin^{n-1}(x)+\frac{n-1}n\int\sin^{n-2}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $\mathrm{d}\cos(x)=-\sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$
$(2)$: integrate by parts
$(3)$: add $(n-1)\int\sin^n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ to both sides and divide by $n$

Modulo a constant of integration, induction and $(3)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
&\int\sin^n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{(n-1)!!}{n!!}x[n\text{ is even}]-\cos(x)\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\rfloor}\frac{(n-1)!!(n-2k)!!}{n!!(n-2k-1)!!}\frac{\sin^{n-2k-1}(x)}{n-2k}\\
&=\frac{(n-1)!!}{n!!}\left(x[n\text{ is even}]-\cos(x)\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\rfloor}\frac{(n-2k-2)!!}{(n-2k-1)!!}\,\sin^{n-2k-1}(x)\right)
\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
where $[\dots]$ are [Iverson Brackets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Answer (score 2):

The usual form of the resulting integral depends, for one, on the parity of $k$ (i.e., whether it is even or odd).

If you really want a general formula, you could expand using the complex representation of $\sin$, namely,
$$\sin z = \frac{\exp(iz) - \exp(-iz)}{2i},$$
expand $\sin^k z$ using the binomial theorem, integral term-by-term (which is easy, since each term is an exponential function), then rewrite the resulting complex expression as a sum of sine and cosine functions.

The above technique may or may not be useful. In general, it is better to do the following: If $k$ is even, use the double angle identity to write the integral in terms of $\cos^{k / 2}$, and handle any terms $\cos^{\ell}$ with even $\ell$ that occur with the same method. If $k$ is odd, say, $k = 2 m + 1$, we can write $$\int \sin^k x \,dx = \int (1 - \cos^2 x)^m \sin x \,dx,$$ after which the substitution $u = \cos x$ transforms the integral into one with a polynomial integrand. Any terms $\cos^{\ell} x$ with odd $\ell$ that occur can be handled analogously.

Comment: Very helpful, especially the second part. I'm trying with the exponential expansion because, as I said, I don't know if K is even or odd. In doing this I ended up with ha series, and there is an "unknown" problem: the series has a pole only if K is even... @Travis