# $\displaystyle \int \sin^{n}(x)dx$ by induction

Tags: integration, discrete-mathematics, induction

We have,

$P(n): \displaystyle \int \sin^{n}(x)dx = -\frac{1}{n}\sin^{n-1}(x)\cos(x)+\frac{n-1}{n}\int \sin^{n-2}(x)dx$

$P(n+1): \displaystyle \int \sin^{n+1}(x)dx = -\frac{1}{n+1}\sin^{n}(x)\cos(x)+\frac{n}{n+1}\int \sin^{n-1}(x)dx$

$\displaystyle \int \sin(x)\sin^{n}(x)dx.$

$u=\sin^{n}(x) \Rightarrow du=n\sin^{n-1}(x)\cos(x)dx$

$dv=\sin(x) \Rightarrow v=-\cos(x)$

So,

$\displaystyle \int \sin^{n+1}(x)dx= -\sin^{n}(x)\cos(x)+n\int \cos^{2}(x)\sin^{n-1}(x)dx$

Now, I'm having difficulty applying the $P(n)$ induction hypothesis. If anyone can contribute to this, I would appreciate it.

Comment: You don't need induction to prove that $P(n)$ holds for every $n\in\Bbb N$. The proof is direct: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1113773

Comment: Use $\cos^2x=1−\sin^2x$
 and if $$P(m)=∫\sin^mx\ dx,P(m+1)=?$$

Comment: @user2661923, I meant this